# Why isn't my picture uploading to my html file

Tags: html

I am currently trying to upload an image above my page's navigation bar, yet every time I try to upload the image, I continuously get the blue question mark in the white box error.

I have tried changing the file extension of the photo

Here is the code for my image

```
<img src="AD.png" width="250" height="100" alt="logo"></img>
```

Also this image is saved in my documents folder.

Comment: Are you serving up the content via a webserver? Is the image in the same directory as the html?

Comment: For that image to work, it should be in the same folder as your `index.html` folder, and the image file should be called `"AD.png"`

Comment: "*this image is saved in my documents folder*". It needs to be a file called `AD.png` in the **same** folder as your HTML file, and if it's on a webserver you also need to make sure that the image has also been uploaded. It's also possible that you've cached the 'errored' file; try clearing your cache. Also, `<img>` has a self-closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code cannot find the image. It looks in its own directory for "AD.png", since "AD.png" is in the documents folder and your code, presumably, is not, it can't find it. You need to the complete filepath.

MacOS: something like `/Users/username/Documents/AD.png`

Windows: something like `C:\Users\username\Documents\AD.png`

To copy the filepath on both platforms is pretty simple. Mac is Option+Right-Click, and then "Copy AD.png as Pathname". Windows you can find the file in File Explorer and then click "Copy path" in the upper left corner.

Happy coding!

Comment: Mark as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) `<img />` is self-closing, so you can write it like this:

```
<img src="AD.png" width="250" height="100" alt="logo" />
```

**N.B.** *In HTML5, it is perfectly acceptable to omit the final slash.*

---

2) This is important. You need to include the file path in the `src` attribute.

**e.g.** If the path to your image is `/documents/ad.png` then you need to write:

```
<img src="/documents/ad.png" width="250" height="100" alt="logo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `<img>` is a self closing tag. (Using a `/>` like `<img src="" />`

But for the file path, it depends on what you want. If you are

- Trying to make a file for yourself, this code validates properly only if your image and your html file is in your documents folder.
- Trying to make it for a class, or somebody else, then you need the full file path e.g
  `<img src="full/file/path" />`

Hope this helps! :)