# cannot upload HTML image to a website, however local file URL works fine

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, file-upload

before you say that it's a duplicate, please read the entire thing.

I have the following piece of code:

```
<title>the-doge.net</title>

<!-- add the image-->
<img src="doge-poster1.png" height="500" width="800" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>

<body style="background-color:black;">

<!--add the login and register buttons-->
<input type="image" src="register.png" style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:50px; right: 7%;"/>
<input type="image" src="login.png" style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:50px; left: 12%;"/>

</body>
```

however, it says

```
Not Found: /login.png
Not Found: /doge-poster1.png
Not Found: /register.png
```

I have looked at various answers on Stack Overflow, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422184/why-isnt-my-picture-uploading-to-my-html-file), and also a few websites like [here](https://encode.host/knowledgebase/25/Why-can-I-not-see-the-images-on-my-website.html) and provided full directory, and a image on img.bb, but it all did not work. Here is my file structure:

```
...
landing(folder)
--migrations (folder)
--templates (folder)
----landing (folder)
------base.html
------doge-poster1.png
------index.html
------login.png
------navbar.html
------register.png
```

note: In PyCharm there is a way to open a local file URL and it works fine, but `python manage.py runserver` doesn't seem to display any of the images.

Comment: You might want to think about putting all your images in a static directory. As long as you know how to set up your project's static directories in your project's `settings.py` folder. All you would have to do would be `<img src="{% static 'login.png' %}>" and make sure to `{% load static %}` at the top of the page

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but can you try like this?

```
<title>the-doge.net</title>

<!-- add the image-->
<img src="./doge-poster1.png" height="500" width="800" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>

<body style="background-color:black;">

<!--add the login and register buttons-->
<input type="image" src="./register.png" style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:50px; right: 7%;"/>
<input type="image" src="./login.png" style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:50px; left: 12%;"/>

</body>
```

Or you can try like this

```
<title>the-doge.net</title>

<!-- add the image-->
<img src="/templates/landing/doge-poster1.png" height="500" width="800" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>

<body style="background-color:black;">

<!--add the login and register buttons-->
<input type="image" src="/templates/landing/register.png" style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:50px; right: 7%;"/>
<input type="image" src="/templates/landing/login.png" style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:50px; left: 12%;"/>

</body>
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: static worked, the answer is in the comments.